# Find Those Chess Notations! #1.5

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

This is this a small puzzle for you all until I come out with a big one for #2.

Number Of Moves: 6

Checkmater: White

Given Game (Regular Chess Notation):

1. ? ?
2. ? ?
3. bxa3 g6
4. ? Ne7
5. ? ?
6. Nh6#

Cryptic Clue: Sometimes trying to keep the king safe doesn’t keep the king safe!

You must logically deduce what moves all of the question marks are. Don’t forget the add the entire notation chart filled in and explanations for every move you fill in!

Images are not required. A mere link to your  game shall suffice. I would prefer that you use [Apronus](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/) please.

(I cannot use lichess for reasons: it’s personal. So don’t use it for a link please. Doing this will make it easier for your answer to get accepted if it is right.)

And yes, noedne, I have confirmed that this can be logically deduced!

Comment: Not to pry, but regarding lichess - would it be reasonable to include both an Apronus link and lichess link?

Comment: Huh. OK. What where those symbols supposed to be?

Comment: ¯|_(ツ)_/¯ Oh well. But tbh, it seems a little fishy that we need to use a specific platform to get a correct answer. You're not affiliated with Apronus, right? Could we use another pgn viewer that isn't lichess or Apronus?

Comment: Never mind; I'm being to nosy. I just can't imagine ever not wanting to use lichess _and_ preferring the lackluster (IMO) apronus. But you said it was personal and I'm not gonna say another word 'cause that's rude. Sometimes I talk too much. My apologies.

Comment: Sure! Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

> [1. Nf3 e6 2. Ne5 Ba3 3. bxa3 g6 4. Bb2 Ne7 5. Ng4 O-O 6. Nh6#](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nf3_e6_Ne5_Ba3_bxa3_g6_Bb2_Ne7_Ng4_O-O_Nh6M)

Sometimes trying to keep the king safe doesn’t keep the king safe:

> refers to castling, which is often used to safely tuck away the king, but enables the mate here.

Some reasoning:

> The only black piece that can reach a3 in two moves (required for 3. bxa3) is the king's bishop. That move conveniently opens the long diagonal for the white queen's bishop, necessary for the mate to function. Only the white king's knight can reach h6 in four moves, for a total of 6 moves by white.

Note that

> the game could also begin 1. Nf3 e5 2. Nxe5, and the white knight has two other options to reach h6 on the sixth move, e.g. Nf3-h4/d4-f5-h6.